# application of fourier series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm on question (c), I'm not sure how to progress:

all I've done is $S = T + \sum_{n = 2k} 1/n^6$ but can't get the required expression. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rewrite that sum you have found by changing $n$ such that the sum goes from $1$ to $\infty$. Recall that $2^6=64$ and you'll get the idea for the change of variable.

Comment: Which sum, S or T?

Comment: The sum of $1/n^6$.